# Digital signature in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, digital-signature

I am developing an APEX 5 application where the user can upload/download his own files. I want the user to be able to digitally sign the files directly in the application by using his own USB token for digital signature.

Is there a way I can do this?

I've seen that it is possible to do this in Node JS, but I couldn't find a way to integrate this with APEX 5.

Comment: Hello, did you manage to get this done?

Comment: Don't use the Salesforce `apex` tag for `oracle-apex` questions.